# Do we use "twice, three times, twofold, threefold" with "decrease, fall, decline, etc"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

> Say,
>
> 2010: the price of that car: 1000 dollars
>
> 2011: the price of that car: 2000 dollars
>
> Look at these some expressions
>
> 1. the price of that car increased twofold from 1000 dollars in 2010 to 2000 dollars in 2011
> 2. the price of that car **increased twice** from 1000 dollars in 2010 to 2000 dollars in 2011 (I think this sentence is not correct because
>    "twice" modifies adverbs?)
> 3. the price of that car in 2011 is twice its price in 2010
> 4. the price of that car in 2011 is two times its price in 2010
> 5. the price of that car doubled from 1000 dollars in 2010 to 2000 dollars in 2011
> 6. That car doubled in price from 1000 dollars in 2010 to 2000 dollars in 2011
>
> 2010: the price of that car: 2000 dollars
>
> 2011: the price of that car: 1000 dollars
>
> 7. the price of that car halved from 2000 dollars in 2010 to 1000 dollars in 2011
> 8. That car halved in price from 2000 dollars in 2010 to 1000 dollars in 2011
> 9. the price of that car decreased twofold from 1000 dollars in 2010 to 2000 dollars in 2011 (I think it's not correct)

Do we use "**twice, three times, twofold, threefold**" with "**decrease, fall, decline, etc**"?

Comment: No, I think **twofold** etc. have to describe an increase. All the others are OK except that **increased twice** would mean 'increased on two occasions', and I would never say 'two times' for 'twice', although apparently some native speakers find that acceptable.

Comment: Terms such as twofold and threefold have both common meanings and technical meanings. You should probably avoid their use unless you have previously made it very clear which you are using. A "twofold increase" could mean "has been folded over twice and so is four times as thick."   My preference for form is #3, but it's only my preference. It is because it is the price that changed.

Comment: @puppetsock That's not a meaning of 'twofold' I have ever heard, and it's not in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/twofold) either. '-fold' is a common suffix meaning '_n_-times as much'. The verb 'fold' definitely cannot be used in combination with numbers in the way you specify. The only exception I can think of is 'manifold', where the original sense of 'many times' has acquired technical meanings in automotive engineering and mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you wouldn't use *twice* to describe a 100% increase. If you say that something "increased twice," that means that it increased once to some unspecified amount and then increased a second time (i.e. increased at two different points between 2010 and 2011). You could, however, say that the $2,000 is ***twice* as much as** the $1,000 price, whereby you're comparing the two prices.

Terms like *twofold* and *threefold* are reserved for increases. The suffix *-fold* is a (positive) **multiplier**, not a divider. Just like you wouldn't say that going from 10 to 5 is doubling, you don't say that going from 10 to 5 is a "twofold decrease"; it's an oxymoron.

Answer (score 1):

Example 2 is confusing because "twice" appears to be modifying the verb "increase" instead of modifying the noun "price" (as in example 3).

The concept of "increase" (the verb or the noun) isn't really countable the same way "price" is countable. An increase doesn't really bring to mind any specific number, so making an increase "twice" (or "two times") means **doubling the process** of increasing a value. That is, having two separate examples where the price went up (an indeterminate amount).

A price has a specific numeric value, so "twice" or "two times the price" means **doubling the value** of the price, which we accomplish via multiplication.